# SFMC Custom Activity - Authenticated Headers JSON

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, custom, marketingcloudapi

I am currently trying to post the following JSON through a custom activity that fires a REST API to an end-point, however I have been provided an api key to include in the header to be able to validate the call. However once I've included the api key in the body of the call as a header, the activity passes validation but does not activate:

```
{
  "name": "",
  "id": "2555d287-0f53-4222-8d03-1eb3603d3a65",
  "key": "REST-1",
  "type": "REST",
  "arguments": {
    "executionMode": "{{Context.ExecutionMode}}",
    "definitionId": "{{Context.DefinitionId}}",
    "activityId": "{{Activity.Id}}",
    "contactKey": "{{Context.ContactKey}}",
    "execute": {
      "inArguments": [
        {
          "contactKey": "{{Contact.Key}}"
        },
        {
          "field1": "{{Contact.Attribute.JourneyEntrySource.field1}}"
        },
        {
          "field2": "{{Contact.Attribute.JourneyEntrySource.field2}}"
        }
      ],
      "url": "https://testurl.com/execute"
    },
    "testExecute": "",
    "startActivityKey": "{{Context.StartActivityKey}}",
    "definitionInstanceId": "{{Context.DefinitionInstanceId}}",
    "requestObjectId": "{{Context.RequestObjectId}}"
  },
  "configurationArguments": {
    "save": "",
    "testSave": "",
    "publish": {
      "url": "https://testurl.com/publish"
    },
    "testPublish": "",
    "unpublish": "",
    "stop": "",
    "testStop": "",
    "testUnpublish": "",
    "partnerActivityId": "",
    "validate": "",
    "testValidate": "",
    "outArgumentSchema": "",
    "executeSchema": ""
  },
  "metaData": {
    "icon": "https://sample-activity.herokuapp.com/icon.png",
    "category": "message",
    "iconSmall": "",
    "original_icon": "icon.png",
    "isConfigured": true
  },
  "editable": true,
  "outcomes": [
    {
      "key": "f0034acf-3422-4859-a719-e0cb43b63b10",
      "next": "WAITBYDURATION-1",
      "arguments": {},
      "metaData": {}
    }
  ],
  "errors": null
}
```